# Converting Buffer to Octet Stream for BunnyCDN

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I wrote my code, I had to upload a file to BunnyCDN. I modified the [@dan-online/bunnycdnjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dan-online/bunnycdnjs)  library and made the upload code as follows.

```js
async Upload(
    path: string,
    filename: string,
    content: string | ReadStream
): Promise<APIResponse<any>> {
    let url = `${this.endpoint}/${this.storageZoneName}/${path}/${filename}`;

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        let options: request.CoreOptions = {
            method: "PUT",
            headers: {
            AccessKey: this.apiKey,
                'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            },
            body: content,
        };

        let handle: request.RequestCallback = (err, res, body) => {
            let HttpResponse = res;
            let _Error = err;
            let IsLocalError = false;
            let Data;

            try {
                let parsed = JSON.parse(body);
                Data = parsed;
            } catch (err) {
                _Error = err;
                IsLocalError = true;
            }

            resolve({
                HttpResponse,
                Error: _Error,
                IsLocalError,
                Data,
            });
        };

        request(url, options, handle);
    });
}
```

I then made the connection as follows.

```js
const BunnyClient = new Bunny({
    apiKey: BUNNY_STORAGE_KEY,
    storageZoneName: BUNNY_STORAGE_ZONE,
    cdnLocation: 'Main'
});
```

Finally, I set Express like this

```js
import fileUpload from 'express-fileupload';

app.use(express.json({limit: '500mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '500mb', extended: true}));
app.use(fileUpload({
    limits: { fileSize: 500 * 1024 * 1024 },
}));
// ...
app.post('/api/_createEpisode', async (req, res) => {
    if (!req.files || ['video'].some(key => !req.files[key])) return res.json(APIResponses.ERROR(
        ErrorCodes.BadRequest,
        {
            'files': 'Err'
        }
    ));

    const {name, data} = req.files.video;

    await BunnyClient.Upload('test', name, data.toString('base64'));
})
```

But when it uploads the file, the content is invalid. How can I solve this problem.
[image: Invalid Content]
The contents of my uploaded file 123.png when saved
[image: Example Content of a Uploaded File]
I have looked for a very long time but I have not found any results that work for me. I hope I can find a solution in here.

Resources:
[BunnyCDN Docs - Upload File](https://docs.bunny.net/reference/put_-storagezonename-path-filename)

Comment: I suggest you add your solution as an answer, not inside the question. So it will be displayed as "answered"

Answer (score 0):

After a little more effort, I tried to send the buffer by typing `data` instead of `data.toString('base64')` and I uploaded it successfully without any problem

```js
import fileUpload from 'express-fileupload';

app.use(express.json({limit: '500mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '500mb', extended: true}));
app.use(fileUpload({
    limits: { fileSize: 500 * 1024 * 1024 },
}));
// ...
app.post('/api/_createEpisode', async (req, res) => {
    if (!req.files || ['video'].some(key => !req.files[key])) return res.json(APIResponses.ERROR(
        ErrorCodes.BadRequest,
        {
            'files': 'Err'
        }
    ));

    const {name, data} = req.files.video;

    await BunnyClient.Upload('test', name, data);
})
```